# Decode/Encode string such as "AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBgQA==" to 130,-90,0 in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary, decode

I need to generate an input into an application which only accepts strings like 
'AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGB4QA=='.

I have a few samples from which I know what the anticipated output should look like:

- "AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBgQA==" should lead to 130,-90,0
- "AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMBiQA==" should lead to 150,-90,0
- "AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGB4QA==" should lead to 390,-90,0

These encodings have been generated in C++ somehow but I have no idea how I can generate them.

**What I would need is a method where i can input numbers (like 130, -90, 0) and it outputs me the string "AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBgQA==".**

I tried to reverse engineer the string a bit, but I did not end up with anything useful so far:

```
print(base64.b64decode('AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGB4QA=='))

b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80V\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`x@'
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track with b64decode. Any help would be fantastic!!!

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem above was :

```
data = base64.b64decode('AQAAAAAAgFbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGB4QA==')

test = struct.unpack('ddd', data[1:])
ver = struct.unpack('b', data[:1])
print(test)
print(ver)
```

output:

```
(-90.0, 0.0, 390.0)
(1,)
```

where 1 is obviously a version number I was not aware of.